# how to have sortable UI in wordpress admin post page within iframe?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, user-interface, iframe, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an iframe in wordpress admin post page and sortable element going to be inside the iframe. jQuery sortable UI working fine out site the iframe but not working inside the iframe. it is giving an error like "**sortable is not a function**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved the issue myself by enqueuing external UI framework link https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the IFRAME is and how you made it. IFRAME is basically a completely new page and you need to load JavaScript, CSS and everything else inside it, it will not use the JS and CSS from the page it is loaded into.

Comment: Hi Milan,
I have already tried what you are suggesting, i enqueued the supporting files to the page which i'm lodging inside the iframe like shown below.

wp_enqueue_script( array("jquery", "jquery-ui-core",  "jquery-ui-sortable", "underscore", "select2") );

but stil it was giving an error like  "**sortable is not a function**"

Comment: For wp_enqueue_script to work, it has to be WordPress front end page - theme powered, with wp_head, wp_footer actions. Enqueue scripts can't just magically work, it requires full theme based page. What page you load in IFRAME?

Comment: Petwovic, yes i'm loading theme based page which is a part of front end.